# Tar Command backup error

Tags: linux, tar

I want to take backup from hard disk to tape drive using NFS server using tar command,but I am getting error message

```
$ tar -czf /dev/st0 /media/seagate expansion drive/disk/file/
tar:/media/seagate :cannot stat:no such file or directory
tar: expansion :cannot stat:no such file or directory
tar: drive/disk/file/ :cannot stat:no such file or directory
tar: error exit delayed from previous error
```

Regards
S K

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get an answer to your question, please provide the tar command you actually ran.

Comment: tar -czf /dev/st0 /media/seagate expansion drive/disk/file/

Comment: You have spaces in the directory names ? In that case: try to quote the complete argument.

Comment: Add the command to your question; don't try to put code in comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
tar -czf /dev/st0 /media/seagate expansion drive/disk/file/
```

When given above command, your shell considers `/media/seagate` and `expansion` and `drive/disk/file/` as separate arguments, so `tar` considers them as different files/directories. If it is a single file, the enclose it with quotes like,

```
tar -czf /dev/st0/file.tar.gz "/media/seagate expansion drive/disk/file/"
```

*Fixed tar filename*